# Publishing dynamic raster data repository using ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to publish raster datasets using ArcGIS server. The dataset grows every 10 days or so and I want the new data to appear in the same service and be able to select it using simple layer selection. Is there any way I can achieve this without destroying the existing service and re-creating it?

I want to know if there is a way I can publish the folder or geo-database containing the raster datasets once in a way where the changes in that folder/geo-database is reflected in the service.

Comment: This sounds like standard WMS operations. You set up a database, you set up a WMS to look at the database, the data that is presented to the user dynamically changes. No need to reconfigure.  Did you look at WMS?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Ok here is the scenario, i published a WMS using a file gdb with "Raster 1" in it but then I add "Raster 2" in the gdb. However, after adding the "Raster 2" my users are not able to see "Raster 2" while they can clearly see "Raster 1". After looking at your comments I have been looking at a few things but the best I can do is publish a WCS trying to share the gdb as a geodata service (as there is no option to select WMS). Am i doing something wrong here?